# Determine joint probability density function and calculate the given probabilities.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I've got this question as one the problems in my homework:

[image]

Here's my attempt of solution:

As the points have all of them the same probability of being chosen, they are uniformly distributed. Accordingly, $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{\pi}$. One can always draw the good and old 45º line where $x=y$. This line crosses the first and third quarters of the cartesian plane. All the points to the right (or below) of it are such that $x>y$. Alternatively, points on the left of it (or above) are such that $x<y$. It includes $(0,0)$, determing a diameter regarding the unit circle. Hence, $\mathbb{P}(X>Y) = \mathbb{P}(X<Y) = \frac{1}{2}$. Only points that fall in the line itself will be such that $x=y$ and because of that $\mathbb{P}(X=Y) = 0$.

Is it right? Any more insights? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your calculations are correct.